# Git push error on local development environment after doing a git reset --hard

Tags: git, github

Earlier today I performed a `git reset --hard 12345abc` to revert my local copy back to a specific commit. Now when I try to push new changes to origin master, I am getting the following error:

*Note: "12345abc" above is an example commit number*

```
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:example/example.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull')
hint: before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

How can I go ahead and commit my new changes and push them to origin master?

Comment: Have you read `git push --help` as it suggests? Or tried to search on Google? This is a common error and has been asked often. You should always use search tools before asking a question here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ git push -f
```

will solve your issue.

Note: unless referred to by other commits, a branch or a tag, `12345abc` and all its child commits will be garbage-collected (since nothing references them anymore, Git assumes they are useless)